# Does Vapor support DELETE from HTML Form?

Tags: swift, vapor

To delete a user through an admin panel i want to fire a delete request from an HTML Form. Does Swift Vapor support put/patch/delete through hidden html input similar to e.g. Laravel? If not what would the proper way to delete something be?

```html
<!-- Laravel example -->
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#form-method-spoofing

Comment: That seems like an ugly Laravel hack and I would be surprised if any other framework supports it.

Comment: I wouldn't call it ugly hack. It's a good workaround to be able to do CRUD operations from html forms.

Comment: Write a middleware to support this kind of hack. Vapor by itself will never support it out of the box I guess.

Comment: @imike i don't need this specifically. I just wanna delete a user. What alternative do i have?

Comment: @Deitsch Handle `onSubmit` and create the request by yourself?

Comment: Send delete request with JavaScript for example, or delete a user via post with form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone wrapping his/her head around the same thing. As the comments already say, i decided to go the way of using a post request. I registered my routes as follows:

```swift
func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) throws {
    let user = routes.grouped("user")
    user.get(use: getAll)
    user.get(":userid", use: getOne)
    user.post(use: create)
    user.post(":userid","delete", use: delete)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`RoutesBuilder`'s `get`, `post` (etc ...) are only helper functions around `on` method.

There is a helper function for `DELETE` `HTTPMethod` :

```swift
func boot(routes: routesBuilder) throws {
    let user = routes.grouped("user")
        user.delete(":userid", use: self.delete)
    ...
}
```

Also, you can manually specify the `HTTPMethod` through the `on` method.

```swift
func boot(routes: routesBuilder) throws {
    let user = routes.grouped("user")
        user.on(.DELETE, ":userid", use: self.delete)
    ...
}
```

Comment: This was not really my question. It was about sending the request from leaf rather than receiving the request. But anyway, good answer. Gotta get the vapor tag going more.